# Calculating time difference between 2 dates in JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I using `JodaTime` and I need to check if 2 dates are in in range of 3 months difference. So I wrote simple method to check this

```
  private boolean inRangeOf3Months(Pair<BusinessData, BusinessData> pair) {     
        return pair.getKey().getDateTimeValue() != null && pair.getValue().getDateTimeValue() != null ? 
            new Period(pair.getKey().getDateTimeValue(), pair.getValue().getDateTimeValue()).getMonths() <= 3 : false;
    }
```

Now I'm writing tests and this one is fine

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnTrueWhenInRangeOf3Months() {          
    BusinessData closingDateFrom = businessData("closingDateFrom");
    closingDateFrom.setDateTimeValue(DateTime.now());

    BusinessData closingDateTo = businessData("closingDateTo");
    closingDateTo.setDateTimeValue(DateTime.now().plusMonths(3));

    ReportingSearchCriteria criteria = criteriaOf(closingDateFrom, closingDateTo);      

    Assert.assertTrue(validator.isSufficient(criteria));        
}
```

But that one is not, I'm setting first date to `now()` and second one to `now().plusMonths(3).plusDays(1)`. So its over my range, it shouldn't be allowed.

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnFalseWhenOverRangeOf3Months() {          
    BusinessData closingDateFrom = businessData("closingDateFrom");
    closingDateFrom.setDateTimeValue(DateTime.now());

    BusinessData closingDateTo = businessData("closingDateTo");
    closingDateTo.setDateTimeValue(DateTime.now().plusMonths(3).plusDays(1));

    ReportingSearchCriteria criteria = criteriaOf(closingDateFrom, closingDateTo);        

    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isSufficient(criteria));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Period of 3 months and a few days still have a difference of 3 months.
So if you want to make it 3 months inclusive you can add one day to last date and use just less than (instead of less than or equal):

```
new Period(pair.getKey().getDateTimeValue(), pair.getValue().getDateTimeValue().plusDays(1)).getMonths() < 3
```

Also, pay attention that the second date should be later the first one (otherwise it won't work).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your comparison must be on total days not on months because for example let's consider today's date as first date and second date with addition of 3 months plus 25 days

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.now();
System.out.println(date1);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.now().plusMonths(3).plusDays(25);
System.out.println(date2);
Period p = new Period(date1,date2);
System.out.println(p.getMonths());
```

**Output**

```
2019-08-09T04:31:07.400-05:00
2019-12-04T04:31:07.449-06:00
3
```

Still it returns difference of months is `3` because the difference is 3 months and 25 days were 4 months not completed yet. Now if you add 3 months plus 30 days to second date it will return difference as `4` months (some times you might need to add 31 days because it depends on month that has 31 days)

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.now();
System.out.println(date1);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.now().plusMonths(3).plusDays(30);
System.out.println(date2);
Period p = new Period(date1,date2);
System.out.println(p.getMonths());
```

**Output**

```
2019-08-09T04:34:29.530-05:00
2019-12-09T04:34:29.579-06:00
4
```

From the above approach you can't even take the months of two days and check whether difference is 3 months or not, because second date may return third month in some cases (like above if date is middle of month and if you add couple of days to it).

I will suggest compare the total days, for example total no of days between two days > 90 or > 91 for this you can  use `Duration`

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.now();
System.out.println(date1);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.now().plusMonths(3).plusDays(1);
System.out.println(date2);
Duration d = new Duration(date1, date2);
System.out.println(d.getStandardDays());
```

**Output**

```
2019-08-09T04:40:47.334-05:00
2019-11-10T04:40:47.381-06:00
93
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easiest is to just compare the 3 month away marks (buth past and future) to the other date.

```
public boolean areWithin3Months(DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2) {
    return !dateTime1.minusMonths(3).isAfter(dateTime2)
        && !dateTime1.plusMonths(3).isBefore(dateTime2);
}
```